# NavigationDrawer+TabView+edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, navigation-drawer, tabview

I am a beginner.I want to make an app that includes following:

-Navigation Drawer
-Tab Swipe View
-Two edittext,one textview and one button for each tab

I will add the screenshots.

I managed to combine Navigation Drawer and tab view.But I have trouble with edittext and textview inside the fragment.I want my textview to display the additon of two edittexts when I click the button.Please help me.Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W62LH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejN0p.png)

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your exact error or problem from your question,
in fragments, did you initialized the text boxes,edit texts and Buttons like this?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_howitworks, container, false);
        edittext=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.ed_id);
        textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        button=( Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bd_id);
}
```

Comment: can you specify the exact error that you are getting

Comment: Yes I did but where to put Java code? Inside fragment class or main activity or fragmentpageradapter class?

Comment: u did the design in the fragment's xml right?..then the code should be in the fragments....i think you should study more about the fragments and android..find some you tube tutorials..